# Unity grid system woes (How to make grid that auto-collapses to column in portrait mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-components

My problem is *very* difficult to describe, so hopefully (with the pictures I provide) someone can help me figure this out. If you are confident you can fix it, I'm willing to pay if I have to. I need this fixed.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to work with the Unity canvas/layout groups. I have a series of canvases that only show one at a time (think of them as screens). Inside each canvas are components (the first one is a graph and timer, and then a data panel and some buttons.

Here is an image of what I'd *like* each of the panels to look like (only one of these will be open at a time):

[image: Unity Canvas]

Essentially, I just want each sub-canvas (the dark gray boxes) to inhabit ~50% x 50% of the screen, and when the orientation is horizontal/vertical, tile them accordingly.

Each Child panel (the dark gray) only needs to change. The children *inside* of the panel can stay and scale relative to the parent canvas.

I have tried EVERYTHING, dug through the documentation, and have run out of options.

Comment: Can you explain _tile them accordingly_ ?

Comment: Imagine two boxes. If it's landscape, they would fix next to each other. If portrait, the right one wraps underneath. So each of them is half the screens longest axis. See the picture for reference

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `Layout Element` to all of those gray panels with a Flexible Width or Height setting? The screenshot below shows how to have two panels that are side by side, both occupying half the width of their container. (Both have a Flexible Width setting of 1.)

[image: Layout element]

The two Panels are children of the Canvas that has a Horizontal Layout group like this:
[image]

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure how to get them to 'stack' -- Or what order to have layout groups in etc. 

Can you explain the hierarchy? Camera > Canvas > Group(layout element?)

Where do I set the pivot and anchor points, etc?

Comment: Also - Remember that based on the user's orientation, it'll either be a horizontal or vertical group. That's where I'm having the issue. It has to be dynamic, as in the user (at any time) can change the orientation, and the blocks will rearrange.

Comment: Then you just need to switch from a vertical to a horizontal layout group, depending on the orientation

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work. I had a flag in an update() that set a bool to isPortrait, and destroyed the gameObject's component vert/horiz depending, and created another, as you can't have both (even if one is disabled).

Comment: Then you could use a grid layout where you switch the row and column counts depending on the orientation.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. What else would have to be configured to allow that? It's also *ridiculously* hard to work with, as the only time there's an actual orientation change is when it's playing (not editor) so I have to kind of 'fly blind' until I play it after build. Makes it VERY difficult to program. What workflow do you use for this type of thing?